# How to convert a byte array to a string?

Tags: c#, encryption, arrays, aes, rijndaelmanaged

Using the function from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

```
public static byte[] encryptStringToBytes_AES(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
```

As you can see it returns a byte array, I want to convert the byte array to a string.

How can I convert it from a byte array to string and visa versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How convert byte array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't care how it's stored, an easy way is to use:

Convert byte array into string: `Convert.ToBase64String(YourByteArray)` and
Convert string into byte array: `Convert.FromBase64String(YourString)`.
  This will give a concise, printable ASCII representation of the byte array.

Answer (score 2):

This can help you a lot, is about to converting into Hex format but can be very usefull
[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit code. It isn't going to work on 8-bit AES ciphertext.

Answer (score 0):

While using Rijndael Encryption i faced this problem, it returns encrypted byte[] (array),
Convert byte[] to string;

```
 myStringVariable= Convert.ToBase64String(myEncryptedByteArray);
```

Convert string to byte[];

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(myStringVariable);
```

For more about [Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Cheers !!!