# Code unit size (width) of a Text.Encoding?

Tags: .net, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, utf

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942142/1879042) about Unicode handling in .Net, John Skeet stated:

> If you're happy ignoring surrogate pairs, UTF-16 has some nice properties, basically due to the size per code unit being constant. **You know how much space to allocate for a given number of code units…**

But how do you know what the codeunit size is, or even whether an encoding is of variable number of codeunits per codepoint?

At first I though that it could be easily determined by calling `GetMaxCharCount(nBytes)` and `GetMaxByteCount(nChars)` functions of a `System.Text.Encoding` instance in question. For example, having 8 input bytes, we will get no more than 8, 4, and 2 decoded characters for ASCII / UTF-8, UTF-16 / UCS-2 and UTF-32 / UCS-4, respectively; yet with 8 input characters we will get 8 bytes for ASCII and some number other than that above for other encodings, which represents their size constancy or variability. However, those functions return hardly useful results:

```
        MaxChars   MaxBytes
         8 bytes    8 chars
---------------------------
ASCII    8 chars    9 bytes   <--- Leftover chars in ASCII? O_o
UTF-8    9 chars   27 bytes
UTF-16   5 chars   18 bytes
UTF-32   6 chars   36 bytes   <--- More chars than UTF-16? O_o
```

This behavior is intentional, though, as their documentation clearly says:

> Note that `GetMaxCharCount` considers the worst case for leftover bytes from a previous encoder operation. For most code pages, passing a value of 0 to this method retrieves values greater than or equal to 1. `GetMaxCharCount(N)` is not necessarily the same value as `N * GetMaxCharCount(1)`.
>
> Note that `GetMaxByteCount` considers potential leftover surrogates from a previous decoder operation. Because of the decoder, passing a value of 1 to the method retrieves 2 for a single-byte encoding, such as ASCII. You should use the `IsSingleByte` property if this information is necessary. `GetMaxByteCount(N)` is not necessarily the same value as `N * GetMaxByteCount(1)`.

That is *not* so clear is how those (or other?) functions may be applied to the task of determining code unit size dynamically rather than from a hardcoded lookup table for a limited number of encodings? The only viable way I found is “if `IsSingleByte` then unit size is 1 byte and character size is constant”, but if it was for single-byte encodings only, then this would not be needed at all. So what is the general solution for arbitrary encodings?

Comment: For `IsSingleByte=False` encodings, the only way I can think of is to loop through every Unicode codepoint (or maybe just a sampling of the more commonly used codepoints) and  encode those using `Encoding.GetBytes()` and then analyze the bytes. For most encodings, the encoded forms of the ASCII characters U-0000 - U-007F will tell you the codeunit size (EBCDIC encodings might be weird), and then you can see whether the non-ASCII codepoints encode to larger multiples of that size.