# how to copy/Convert first item in ArrayList to string in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy first item of the array list to a string variable. I did the following but it returns System.Byte[].Please help

```
    for(i=0; i<= ArrayList.Count;i++)
    {
    String TEST = ArrayList[i].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` ? It seems that your array list has an array of bytes. See: [How convert byte array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string)

Comment: `String TEST = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])ArrayList[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, that the code it returning an object, which is `System.Byte[]` array.

```
ArrayList[i].ToString(); // System.Byte[]
```

..no matter how many times you do it. It will always return to be the same.

Use this instead

```
using System.Text; // <-- add this

// inside the code

for(i = 0 ; i <= ArrayList.Count ; i++ )
{
   string TEST = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ArrayList[i]);
}
```

..this will encode the bytes to a string representation of the data.

Answer (score 4):

> it returns System.Byte[]

The default behavior of `.ToString()` just outputes the name of the type of the object.  It is overridden in some types (like value types) to show some representation of the value of the object.  Since `ToString` is not overridden for arrays you are just seeing the type name.

There are multiple ways (ASCII, UTF8, Unicode) to convert a `Byte[]` to a string, so you need to specify which one to use.  If you want to use the default encoding for the system use

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ArrayList[i]);
```

Comment: thank you everyone ,Encoding.Unicode.GetString() worked

Comment: @NicholeGrace For the record, Unicode is a character set and UTF-16 is an encoding for Unicode. Unfortunately, .NET's Encoding classes use `Unicode` to mean UTF-16.