# C# converting byte array to string

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a string in binary format, but **Convert.ToString()** returns unexpected results. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] x = { 0xB1, 0x53, 0x63 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            str.Append(Convert.ToString(x[i], 2));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

The output is:

1011000110100111100011

---

I expected the output to be:

**1011_0001_0101_0011_0110_0011** (0xB15363)

And not:

**1011_0001_1010_0111_1000_11**

Comment: have you googled this also `SO` has several examples as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. Did you really expect there to be underscores? If not, please don't complicate the question by providing something other than the _actual_ literal output that you expected, and which was output instead.

Comment: No, I did not expectet the output to contain underscores, I wanted to make it easier to read

Comment: The underscores made me assume that you were grouping by bytes (well, half bytes) so my first thought is that you were saying it was truncating the last two digits. Putting delimiters between bytes in the actual output would probably have made it more readable (and probably told you what the problem was given the answers given).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pad with zeros you'll get the answer

```
public static void Main()
{        
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] x = { 0xB1, 0x53, 0x63 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        str.Append(Convert.ToString(x[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KjAuBD)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
str.Append(Convert.ToString(x[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

Comment: @Cristi As **Vlad** wrote, the issue is that there are no leading zeros. It is easy to see by adding an extra space between numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You actually just not get leading zeroes.

`01010011` will be just `1010011`.

You have to add leading zeroes by any of the possible methods (`Convert.ToString` doesn't seem to have needed overload). `PadLeft` is mentioned in other answers, adding `new string('0', 8 - s.Length)` will do as well (but [requires a temporary](http://ideone.com/PaJebR)).

Comment: @DJKRAZE: This answers the question "what am I doing wrong".

Comment: before you edited it you just had a question not the coded results

Comment: I can't help think that a solution to the problem might be a bit more in keeping with the site too... Though other answers do that now anyway.