# Upload binary data and other fields to mvc action from code with WebClient or HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a controller action that looks like this

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public int Save(int id, string someField, int someOtherField, byte[] content)
    {
    }
}
```

In another application I need to upload some data to this action either using WebClient or HttpWebRequest. How would I use one of these classes to upload data to this action?

Comment: You can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx
`public byte[] UploadValues(
 string address,
 NameValueCollection data
)`

Creating a NameValueCollection of your post parameters

Comment: @Flatlineato NameValueCollection only supports string values. For the numbers it's easy but is there any other way than to base64 code the byte array (which is a binary file)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string