# How can I determine the current code page in a portable class library?

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-core

I'm trying to port a class library that is reading files from a standard class library to a portable class library (.NET Standard,Version=v1.6), supporting ASP.NET Core.

I need convert a portion of a byte array to a string.

With .NET Framework 4.5 I could detect current code page with

```
public string ConvertToString(byte[] data, int count)
{
int CurrentCodePage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage;
return Encoding.GetEncoding(CurrentCodePage).GetString(data, 0, count);
}
```

A tool Analyze Assembly Portability gave me an advice: "Use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`."
But there is no information about current code page.

How can I convert byte[] to string in current enconding?

**Edit:**
I'm porting a zip-compression library. And in my case I need convert byte[] to string properly. In other q&a (like [How convert byte array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/)) i saw using Encoding. I realized that it was the wrong approach. How can I make convert on right way?

Comment: I'd argue that "current code page" is a Windows-specific concept which might not have an equivalent on all operating systems where ASP.NET Core is supported. Why do you even need "the server's current legacy ANSI codepage" in a web application?

Comment: there are virtually no scenarios where the current OS codepage is relevant *anyway* (you should be explicit when specifying encodings); what is the case that you need here?

Comment: I'm porting a zip-compression library. And in my case I need convert byte[] to string properly. In other q&a (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string) i saw using Encoding. I realized that it was the wrong approach. How can I make convert on right way?

Answer (score -1):

public string ConvertToString(byte[] data, int count)
{

return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data,0,count);
}