# C#: Socket not receiving the message properly?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to show the message in a string that was sent by the client. I coded a simple client application and then coded a server with DotNetty. The client app is just for testing.

Client:

```
var ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 1232;

var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

try
{
    socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port));
}
catch (SocketException se)
{

}

byte[] forwardMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("lol");
socket.Send(forwardMessage);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Server decoder:

```
internal class Decoder : MessageToMessageDecoder<IByteBuffer>
{
    protected override async void Decode(IChannelHandlerContext context, IByteBuffer input, List<object> output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket says: " + input.ToString());
    }
}
```

When sending a message from the client to the server I get this.

```
Socket says: InstrumentedUnpooledHeapByteBuffer(ridx: 0, widx: 3, cap: 1024)
```

Comment: you sent 3 bytes; you received 3 bytes; what makes you think there's a problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string

Answer (score 3):

`input` is a `IByteBuffer`, which is an abstraction around where that data is currently stored - in this case apparently a `InstrumentedUnpooledHeapByteBuffer`, but that doesn't really matter.

You can get the original data via a *wide range* of methods on `IByteBuffer`, but it looks like the simplest for you is simply:

```
var s = input.GetString(input.ReaderIndex, input.WriterIndex, yourEncoding);
```

(or something similar with a `0` and a `3` from one of `input`'s properties)

where `yourEncoding` is the text encoding to use. Note that at the caller you used `Encoding.Default`, but this is a terrible choice, as this is machine-specific; I could *guess* what it might be for you, but I genuinely can't *know* what your `Encoding.Default` is. A better choice would be something like `Encoding.UTF8` (at both ends).

Comment: `input` doesn't have a method `GetString` so your answer is invalid.

Comment: @seegal https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/blob/33b95cfe615bc000bebb247504473ed9d34d0938/src/DotNetty.Buffers/IByteBuffer.cs#L496 - if that isn't the version you're using, then you'll have to use whatever *is* available