# How to send protobuf via socket.io in Unity

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, protocol-buffers

I have created a game that works with `Socket.io` and sends info as JSON object to node.js.
Now I decided to replace JSON with the `Protobuf` protocol.

How should I make a string serialized in Unity and then use `socket.emit("anyevent",ProtobufsObject);` 
and send it to node.js `socketio` listener?

I know how use `protobufs` in unity 
just can't figure it out how to send `protobuf` via `socketio`.

Comment: You could checkout this https://forum.unity.com/threads/protobuf-net-unity-is-it-worth-it.288007/ on how to define your objects to be serializable via Protobuf.
Then, if the protobuf serializer does not return a string, it should return a byte array. Checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string on how to convert the byte array to string in order to send it via the web socket. It could be possible that you can send the byte array directly, but I am not sure if the websocket libraries you use support it.

Comment: tnQ. yes currently I do such way like yours ..I will comeback after completing my project  and write complete solution for others ,too.

Comment: Awesome, I am moving the comment to the answers. Of course, If you find a better way you can edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could check out [how to define your objects to be serializable via Protobuf](https://forum.unity.com/threads/protobuf-net-unity-is-it-worth-it.288007).
- Then, if the protobuf serializer does not return a string, it should return a byte array. Check out [how to convert the byte array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string) in order to send it via the web socket.

It could be possible that you can send the byte array directly, but I am not sure if the web socket libraries you use support it