# Convert IByteBuffer to String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I am working on existing project which is built using DotNetty library, mostly networking framework. I am not that much aware with this framework but as a quick fix, I want to convert IByteBuffer value to the String.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string) one?

Comment: @Anonymous: yes but IByteBuffer looks quite different than Stream and Byte[].

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this library, but there is a ReadString method on IByteBuffer. Is that not what you want? If not, clarify what you mean by "convert" because that can sometimes mean different things.

Comment: @MikeZboray yes there is ReadString method but as I am new to this library as well, not sure how to get parameter value to that method. Looking for some quick help.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really for "quick help". You're supposed to ask a question after reading the documentation, trying a few things, looking around etc. Unless you have the good luck of happening on someone who's using DotNetty, it's rather unlikely you'll get any help with your problem if you're not a lot more specific, especially if it's not something we can easily try on our own, and when it's something that should really be in the documentation.

Comment: @Luaan: You are true manager. Although, fire fighting is always a different story.

Answer (score 1):

`IByteBuffer` represents a stream of binary data of various data types, not a string.

If you want a dump of all the bytes in the buffer, you can use `ByteBufferUtil.HexDump`. This gives you a string of the individual bytes in hexadecimal. This is useful for troubleshooting, if the buffer doesn't contain quite the data you are expecting - you can go tracing the data byte by byte, and find where it goes wrong.

If you want to interpret the bytes differently, you really need to know the types in the buffer. There's no generic method, because the buffer isn't self-descriptive (unlike e.g. XML). If you're trying to get a quick look at the string data in the buffer, and the data happens to be encoded in ASCII, you can try something like this:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer.Array)
```

Needless to say, unless the whole buffer contains an ASCII string, this will produce lots of garbage. Whether this is useful or not depends entirely on the data you're working with; if the buffer has something like an HTTP request, you'll probably see the data just fine. Needless to say, this should only be used for debugging purposes - for any production use, you should really know the layout of the buffer explicitly, rather than guessing at it.